# Control distance between actionButton and downloadButton

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that features a `downloadButton` and an `actionButton` that are separated:

[image]

Here is the reproducible code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Minimal App"),
  hr(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      "Placeholder"
    ),
    mainPanel("Placeholder",
              br(),
              fluidRow("Placeholder"),
              fluidRow(
                column(2, downloadButton("download")),
                column(1, actionButton("send_email", "Email", icon = icon("inbox")))
              )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I minimize the space between the "Download" button and the "Email" button? I want to make the space between them closer, but not zero pixels. The YouTube buttons are a good example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `splitLayout`:

```r
    mainPanel("Placeholder",
              br(),
              fluidRow("Placeholder"),
              fluidRow(
                column(
            3, 
            splitLayout(
              downloadButton("download"),
                      actionButton("send_email", "Email", icon = icon("inbox"))
            )
                )
              )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer. Do you know how to make the buttons have rounded corners, like the Youtube buttons in my post?

Comment: @HowardBaek See https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_buttons.asp

Answer (score 1):

u can add styling to your shiny App in different ways.
see [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/css/).

a fast solution would be

```
  actionButton("send_email", "Email", icon = icon("inbox")) %>%
    tagAppendAttributes(
      style = "border-radius: .5rem;"
    )
```

same goes for downloadButton